# How many (3x3) square arrangements?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

> In how many ways can we place 9 identical squares - 3 red, 3 white and 3 blue, in a 3x3 square in a way that each row and each column has squares of each three colours?

Let the colors be $RGB$, let the white=green for simplicity, then the top row has the following cases:

$RGB, RBG, BRG, BGR, GRB, GBR = 6$ cases.

Take the $RGB$ configuration first: we have:

$$R G B $$

Below $R$ there are two possibilities, $G, B$, suppose you choose $G$ so now we have:

$R G B$

$G$ ==> Now there are two choices there: $R, B$ then one choice for the last one, and for the whole row beneath, one choice each.

If you chose $B$ then you would have had:

$R G B$

$B$ ==> Only one choice left $(R)$ and then one again for last, and the one choice for each of the spots in the last row.

In total, there are $2 + 1 = 3$ possible arrangements here, it would have been the same for the other cases ($GBR, RBG$, etc...).

**The final answer should be $6(3) = 18$,** but the actual answer is $9$?

Comment: Put another way, this asks for the number of $n \times n$ Latin squares of size $n = 3$ (the count for general $n$ is the content of the sequence https://oeis.org/A002860 ), or equivalently, the number of quasigroup structures on a set of $n$ elements.

Answer (score 2):

"In total, there are 2+1=32+1=3 possible arrangements here"

No, you don't add them. You multiply them.  2 choices for the second row and each choice yields 1 choice for the third.

"In total, there are 2x1=2 possible arrangements here"

=======

There are six ways you can do the first row.

In the second row there are 2 choices of color you can put under the red square in the first row.  Call that color x.  There is only one choices to put under the x square in the first row (not red and not x).  Then there's only one choice for the last square of the 2nd row.  So there are 2 choices for the second row.

There is only 1 choice for the third row.

So 12 possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

There are $3!=6$ ways to put the squares in the first row,

and then 2 ways to complete the first column.

This completely determines the square, so there are $6(2)=12$ possibilities

Answer (score 1):

When you complete $G==$, you can't have GRB because that would put two $B$s in the right-hand column.  So I think you have 6(2)=12, not 9.

Comment: that was my first answer, but that was wrong too!